# PHP nested includes in batch php process

Tags: php, nested, include

My problem is in a php batch job which contains nested includes. If I run the job from a shortcut on my desktop everything is fine. If the job is started by the Task Scheduler (which is how is has to run in production), the nested includes refuse to be executed. My webserver is IIS on Windows Server.
Structure of the job shown below.

file1.php is the small "main" module, file3.php does the actual work.
The dir holding file1.php contains dira1 and dirb1.
The includes in file1.php are executed as normal.
The includes in file3.php are executed if the job runs via my shortcut. If the job runs via the Task Scheduler, they are not. If I put the complete job in file1.php (so with inlcludes but not nested), the job runs successfully.

file1.php:

```
include 'dira1/file2.php';
include 'dira1/dira2/dira3/file3.php';
```

file3.php:

```
include 'dirb1/dirb2/file4.php';
include 'dira1/dira2/dira3/file5.php';
```

Thanks for your help.
JackNWK

Comment: Use absolute file paths instead of relative paths.

Comment: Especially true when running something as a cron job.

Answer (score 2):

PHP includes the `__DIR__` constant for this very purpose.  `__DIR__` refers to the directory the current script is located in.

I always recommend including files using the `__DIR__` constant with the relative path from the current script.

```
include __DIR__ . '/dirb1/file2.php';
```

Comment: Solved!!
Before my posting I tried $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. (which gives me the document root) whith  no success.
__DIR__ . gives me the current dir (so dira3 in my example).
At first, this did not help (for the Task Scheduler scenario).
Then, I tried the follwing:
include __DIR__ . '/../../../dirb1/dirb2/file4.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../../../dira1/dira2/dira3/file5.php';
That works for both the shortcut and the Task Scheduler scenario.
Thanks to all of you for your help!